# Chatter Rest Api Usage

Tags: chatter

We have a 3rd party application, we would like to capture the communication(s) happening on the 3rd party application as Chatter feed on Case within Salesforce.

Can we use Chatter Rest API to push the data from 3rd party application as a chatter feed on case object.

IF Chatter rest API is not the viable option, can anyone please suggest the feasible options to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes, you can use the Connect API to post to the Case Feed. However I am not sure if its the correct solution. It really depends on how much data you want to store, how often the application will push that information to Salesforce (there are Connect API Limits) and what kind of information you want to store.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We are on unlimited edition.  I believe for unlimitied edition there is a minimum of 5000 calls per Salesforce user license and maximum of unlimited. Cant we use Chatter Rest api for this purpose or Connect API (chatter for apex) ; how these two are different; in terms when either of these API's should be used.Again Thank you so much for your answer..

Comment: Differences in the APIs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_using_chatter_connect.htm

Chatter Rest API Limits:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_rate_limits.htm